# test icons in SVG format

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

How to test an icon added in button? This button triggers opening the menu. `menuTriggerLabel` is const.

```
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import { ExpandLess, ExpandMore } from '@material-ui/icons';
import React from 'react';

export const myMenuTriggerLabel = 'My menu';

export const MyMenu = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleToggle = () => {
    setOpen((prevOpen) => !prevOpen);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleToggle} endIcon={open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}>
        {myMenuTriggerLabel}
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I want to test if icon is `ExpandMore`, click on button, test if icon is `ExpandLess`, click on button again and test if icon is `ExpandMore`.

```
it('should render proper icon on show and hide', async () => {
  const component = render(<MyMenu />);
  const icon = component.getByText(menuTriggerLabel)
  ???
```

I know how to click on button. I don't know how to assert icon.

Comment: What's the code for `<ExpandLess />` and `<ExpandMore />`?  I imagine that you'd simply distinguish open from closed by putting the open icon in one's `render()` and the closed icon in the other's `render()`.

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle, codesnipt link?

Comment: @M.M.H.Masud I've edited the question and added full `MyMenu` component source.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with react-testing library.
But i'm for jest+Enzime. Main idea to test it by component selection.

It could be something like for jest+Enzime.

```
const checkOpenState = (tree, state) => {
    expect(!!tree.find(ExpandLess).length).toBe(state)
};
const checkCloseState = (tree, state) => {
   expect(!!tree.find(ExpandMore).length).toBe(state)
};
const toggleState = (tree) => {
   tree.find(Button).props().onClick();
}
it('should render proper icon on show and hide', async () => {
  const component = shallow(<MyMenu />);
  checkOpenState(component, false);
  checkCloseState(component, true);

  toggleState(component);

  checkOpenState(component, true);
  checkCloseState(component, false);
```

For react-testing-library you can look to doc and adapt my solution)

Comment: In generated DOM (looking at browser console) there are no possibility to find `ExpandLess` nor `ExpandMore` thus I can't find them during tests as RTL sees only DOM of component.

Comment: In that case could you check prop 'endIcon' to have correct value?

Comment: I don't know how to do this using React Testing Library

Comment: I'll update my answer for react testing library tomorrow)